# star next to arrowhead in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

What's the best way to draw `$\to^*$` arrows in TikZ drawings?  The best I've managed to come up with so far is

```
\draw[->] (A) to node[very near end] {$*$} (B);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Ι understand your question

Comment: I have a relation $\to^*$ in my work, and I'd like to draw a TikZ diagram involving this relation.  I know how to draw arrows and label them (and different arrowheads can be specified in a straightforward way), but I don't know if there's an easy/natural way to specify this kind of symbol.  Ideally, I'd like something like \draw[->*] for example.

Comment: Can you give  a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: One possibility (though not ideal): `\tikz{\draw[->,semithick] (0,0) -- (.35,0) node[above right, xshift=-.8ex,yshift=-.5ex]  {\scriptsize $*$};}`

Comment: Another possibly is to add  `to*` as an arrow. Could you post either a MWE or a picture of how the star should be aligned in relation to the arrow?

Comment: Ah, that's what I'm looking for I think.  I'm not sure I have an MWE; just something in TikZ that looks like $\to^*$ so I guess the star would be close to, and a little bit above the arrow tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here some ideas.

The first, a `to path` with an extra node consisting of `$ {} ^ * $`.

The second introduces two to arrows, namely `to*` and `*to`. As the arrow will get transformed I have added the `*to` arrow for the start line where the asterisk should appear on the left side of the line.

The code has—commented out—a solution with an original `$\scriptstyle *$` inside a `\pgftext` command which does not work when the arrow is used more than once in the document.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{plotmarks}
\tikzset{
    to*/.style={
        shorten >=.25em,#1-to,
        to path={-- node[inner sep=0pt,at end,sloped] {${}^*$} (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}
    },
    to*/.default=
}

\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{to*}{to*}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=-0.84pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-1.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.21pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.625\pgflinewidth%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by2.5pt%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \begingroup
    \pgftransformxshift{2.5pt}
    \pgftransformyshift{2pt}
    \pgftransformscale{.7}
    \pgfuseplotmark{asterisk}
  \endgroup
%  \pgftext[left,y=2pt]{$\scriptstyle *$}
}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{*to}{*to}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=-0.84pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-1.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=0.21pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.625\pgflinewidth%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by2.5pt%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+\pgfutil@tempdima}
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.28pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.3\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetroundcap
  \pgfsetroundjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{0.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathcurveto
  {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-0.25\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-2.75\pgfutil@tempdima}{-2.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  {\pgfqpoint{-3\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \begingroup
    \pgftransformxshift{2.5pt}
    \pgftransformyshift{-2pt}
    \pgftransformscale{.7}
    \pgfuseplotmark{asterisk}
  \endgroup
%  \pgftext[left,y=-2pt]{$\scriptstyle *$}
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\testtostar}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{
    \node (A) {$A$}; \node at (1,0) (B) {$B$};
    \draw[arrows=#1] (A) -- (B);}%
}
\begin{document}
$ A \to^* B$
\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]{
    \node (A) {$A$}; \node at (1,0) (B) {$B$};
    \path (A) edge[to*] (B);}

\testtostar{-to*}
\testtostar{to*-}
\testtostar{to*-to*}

\testtostar{-*to}
\testtostar{*to-}
\testtostar{*to-*to}

\testtostar{*to-to*}
\testtostar{to*-*to}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Possible improvement: Defining an arrow tip with only the `*` and combine that with `>` so that `>*` can be used similar to `>|` and the `>` option. See also [TikZ arrow tip is displaced](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051).