# TikZ arrow tip is displaced

Tags: tikz-pgf

My quetion is twofold:

1) I want to have a timeline graph with some intervalls. This is my code:

```
\draw[->|] (8,5)--(10,5);
\node[] (sh4) at (9.5,5.5){$s^{\text{h}}_{4}$};
\draw[|<-] (10,5)--(13,5);
\node[] (stt4) at (11,5.5){$STT_{4}$};
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The problem is the bold vertical line of the arrow tip. They should be exactly at the same position, such that the vartical line is thinner.

2) How can I make the arrow tips like `-]`? The following is not working. Seems like one must escape the `]`:

```
\draw[-]] (8,5)--(10,5);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Previous versions of this answer used the now deprecated `arrows` library.
The newer (but at this point old) `arrows.meta` library allows for a very easy solution for your first problem. The [old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/111053/2) can be find in the history. We'll be using `Bar` instead of `|` and `Bracket` instead of `]`, however, we will define `|` and `]` as shorthands again (via the `.tip` handler).

The arrows are usually defined in a way so that they *touch* the point they point to.
You want the `|` arrow parts to extend over that point. You can either use `shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth` or, more comfortably, a slightly changed definition of the arrow tips.
In the code below, this is denoted by the `'` behind the shorthand.

Since `]` will be a troublemaker in many places for options we can simply define a(nother) shorthand.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  |-|/.tip   = Bar[],
  |'-|'/.tip ={Bar[sep=0pt -.5 1]},
  [-]/.tip   = Bracket[],
  ['-]'/.tip ={Bracket[sep=0pt -.5 1]},
  (-)/.tip   = Parenthesis[],
  ('-)'/.tip ={Parenthesis[sep=0pt -.5 1]},
  % aliases
  brack/.tip  = ],
  brack'/.tip = ]',
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=To,
  p/.pic={\draw[pic actions](left:.3)--(0,0);\draw[pic actions](right:.3)--(0,0);}
]
\matrix[
  row sep=1mm,
  row 1/.style={nodes={anchor=base,font=\scriptsize}},
  column 2/.style={shorten >=+-.5\pgflinewidth}
]{
  \node{normal}; & \node{shortening}; & \node{new tip}; \\
  \pic[->|]   {p}; & \pic[->|]   {p}; & \pic[->.|']  {p}; \\
  \pic[-{]}]  {p}; & \pic[-{]}]  {p}; & \pic[-{]'}]  {p}; \\
  \pic[-brack]{p}; & \pic[-brack]{p}; & \pic[-brack']{p}; \\
  \pic[-)]    {p}; & \pic[-)]    {p}; & \pic[-)']    {p}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: superb answer! THX.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How would you do this with parenthesis?

Comment: @Jon I've updated my answer. The newer (but at this point also old) `arrows.meta` library provides a very easy interface to alter arrow tips.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for updating the answer!