# Add distance line into two points in latex-tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sometimes I want to add a line indicating the distance between two points as in the example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,3);
    \coordinate (C) at (8,0);
    \coordinate (D) at (5,1.125);

    % drawing triangle
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A);
    
    % drawing line in triangle
    \draw [dashed] (5,0) -- (D);

    % drawing d line
    \draw  (0,-0.5) -- node[below] {$d$} (8,-0.5);
    \draw (0,-0.4) -- (0,-0.6);
    \draw (8,-0.4) -- (8,-0.6);
    
    % drawing x line
    \draw (5.175,1.593) -- node[above, rotate=-20.556] {$x$} (8.175,0.468);
    \draw (5.14,1.499) -- (5.21,1.686);
    \draw (8.14,0.374) -- (8.21,0.561);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But doing it like this is time consuming as there are a lot of calculations to do. Is there a way to do it automatically so that I can draw the lines with one command without calculations and autorotation? For example:

```
%drawing d line
\draw [offset=-0.5, amplitude=0.2] (A) -- node[below] {$d$} (C)
% drawing x line
\draw [offset=0.5, amplitude=0.2] (D) -- node[above] {$x$} (C)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (C) at (8,0);
\coordinate (D) at (5,1.125);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (5,0) -- (D);
\dimline[extension start length=-0.5 cm, extension end length=-0.5 cm] {($(A)!.5cm!-90:(C)$)} {($(C)!.5cm!90:(A)$)}{d};
\dimline[extension start length=0.5 cm, extension end length=0.5 cm] {($(D)!.5cm!90:(C)$)} {($(C)!.5cm!-90:(D)$)}{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle with dimension lines]

If you prefer the more ugly way without `dimline` :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (C) at (8,0);
\coordinate (D) at (5,1.125);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw [dashed] (5,0) -- (D);
\draw[|-|] ($(A)!.5cm!-90:(C)$) --node[below, sloped]{d} ($(C)!.5cm!90:(A)$);
\draw[|-|] ($(D)!.5cm!90:(C)$) --node[above, sloped]{x} ($(C)!.5cm!-90:(D)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Triangle with dimlines]

**Edit:**

Comment by @Qrrbrbirlbel

> The |-| arrow tips will only touch the targeted points and will not be
> directly orthogonally above the points.

That is actually what you would expect from a dimension line - just like in the `tikz-dimline` package. -see picture from manual:

[image: End arrow with triangle and bar]

If one want the arrow tip centered orthogonal over the point, it can be done with the `sep` option like this:

```
\draw[{|[sep=0pt -0.5]}-{|[sep=0pt -0.5]}] ($(D)!.5cm!90:(C)$) --node[above, sloped]{x} ($(C)!.5cm!-90:(D)$);
```

Comment: Nitpicking: The `|-|` arrow tips will only touch the targeted points and will not be directly orthogonally above the points. (Related: [Q111051](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051))

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(9,4)
    \psset{linejoin=1,PointSymbol=none, PointName = none, dash=3.5pt 2pt}
    \pstTriangle(0,0){A}(0,3){B}(8,0){C}
    \pnodes(5,0){D}(5,1.125){E}
    \psset{linewidth=0.5pt}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](D)(E)
    \pcline[offset=-12pt]{|-|}(A)(C) \nbput{$d$}
    \pcline[offset=12pt]{|-|}(E)(C) \naput[nrot=:U]{$x$}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]