# Vertical Bars at the end of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to recreate the picture attached. For some reason, I can't use the Triangle-Triangle code between two vertical bars using the draw command.  I have tried different combinations, but with now luck.  Here is my MWE. Thank you for your time and any help you can offer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\title{Basic Tikz Graphs}
\author{nbennett }
\date{February 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[important line/.style={thick}]
\draw [opacity=1,important line] (-2,4) -- (2,4) -- (0,0) -- cycle;%big triangle
\draw [important line,fill=white,opacity=1] (0,4) circle (2cm and 0.4cm);%top of cone
\draw [fill=blue!20!white,opacity=1] (-1.49,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=blue!10!white,opacity=1,] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm); 
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,4) --(2,4); %dashed lines
\draw (1,4.18) node{\scriptsize $ 2 $}; % number
\draw[dashed] (0,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98); %dashed line
\draw (0.745,3.12) node{\scriptsize $ r $};
\draw[|Triangle-Triangle|] (2.4,0) -- (2.4,4); %PROBLEM IS HERE
\draw[white, fill=white] (2.3,1.75) rectangle (2.5,2.25); %an empty box for the space in middle
\draw (2.4,2) node{\scriptsize $ 10 $}; %a number
\draw[|Triangle-Triangle|] (1.65,0) -- (1.65,2.98); %PROBLEM HERE TOO
\draw[white, fill=white] (1.65,1.29) rectangle (1.65,1.69);
\path(1.65,1.29)--(1.65,1.69)node[midway]{\scriptsize \(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Made the updates, I know what the error says, I am unable to rectify the error. I also uploaded the picture.

Comment: I did try that earlier, I still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for an [`arrows` specification](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#sec-16.4.1) are somewhat convoluted.

The gist of it is that tip names that aren't single letter need to be ended by options, even if they're empty.

So, using

```
| Triangle[]-Triangle[] |
```

would be the correct way to specify your arrow tip.
However, since that contains `]` you will need to protect this from the option parser (that looks for a `]`):

```
\draw[{| Triangle[]-Triangle[] |}] …;
% or explicitly
\draw[arrows={| Triangle[]-Triangle[] |}] …;
```

The special [`>` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#tikz/%3E) can be used to maybe make this more easier:

```
\draw[>=Triangle, |<->|] …;
```

That said, you can always specify your own tip, say

```
TriBar/.tip = {Triangle[] Bar[]}
```

which you can later use as

```
\draw[TriBar-TriBar] …;
```

If you need this tip often in a picture/scope, you again use

```
> = TriBar
```

and then simply use `<->` on the paths.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[important line/.style={thick}]
\draw [opacity=1,important line] (-2,4) -- (2,4) -- (0,0) -- cycle;%big triangle
\draw [important line,fill=white,opacity=1] (0,4) circle (2cm and 0.4cm);%top of cone
\draw [fill=blue!20!white,opacity=1] (-1.49,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=blue!10!white,opacity=1,] (0,3) circle (1.49cm and 0.3cm); 
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,4) --(2,4); %dashed lines
\draw (1,4.18) node{\scriptsize $ 2 $}; % number
\draw[dashed] (0,2.98) -- (1.49,2.98); %dashed line
\draw (0.745,3.12) node{\scriptsize $ r $};
\draw[{| Triangle[]-Triangle[] |}] (2.4,0) -- (2.4,4); % ← !
\draw[white, fill=white] (2.3,1.75) rectangle (2.5,2.25); %an empty box for the space in middle
\draw (2.4,2) node{\scriptsize $ 10 $}; %a number
\draw[>=Triangle, |<->|] (1.65,0) -- (1.65,2.98); % ← !
\draw[white, fill=white] (1.65,1.29) rectangle (1.65,1.69);
\path(1.65,1.29)--(1.65,1.69)node[midway]{\scriptsize \(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related: [Q111051](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111051)

Comment: Thank you @qrrbrbirlbel for the help and for the detailed explanation.  It worked perfectly. I only need this for one figure, but your explanation was easy to follow. Thank you so much.